# Is the complexity of this topological sort algorithm O(P+D) where P is projects and D is dependencies?

Tags: c++, graph, time-complexity, topological-sort

I have written a topological sorting algorithm in c++ but i am not sure if the complexity is as good as it should be. I know theres a topological sort algorithm that works in O(P+D) time where p is projects and D is number of dependencies, but I am unsure if i wrote it correctly. Can you take a look? Code is below. Any other suggestions on improvement is welcome too, I feel like having 2 lists for adjacency is inefficient and I think there should be a better way to do it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(vector<string> projects, vector<pair<string,string>> dependencies)
    {   
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i< projects.size();i++)
        {
            strToInt[projects[i]]=counter++;    
        }
        adjList.resize(projects.size());
        for(int i=0;i<dependencies.size();i++)
        {
            adjList[strToInt[dependencies[i].second]].first.insert(strToInt[dependencies[i].first]);
            adjList[strToInt[dependencies[i].first]].second.push_back(strToInt[dependencies[i].second]);
        }
    }

    vector<pair<unordered_set<int>,vector<int>>> adjList;
    unordered_map<string,int> strToInt;

    bool BuildOrder(){
        vector<int> visited(adjList.size(),0);
        queue<int> q;
        int count =0;
        for(int i=0;i<adjList.size();i++)
        {
            if(adjList[i].first.size()==0)
            {
                count++;
                q.push(i);
            }
        }
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            count++;
            int temp=q.front();
            q.pop();
            visited[temp]=1;
            for(int i=0;i<adjList[temp].second.size();i++)
            {
                adjList[i].first.erase(temp);
                if(adjList[i].first.size()==0&&visited[i]==0)
                {
                    q.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if(count==visited.size())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<string> projects {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
    vector<pair<string,string>> dependencies{
        {"a","d"},
        {"f","b"},
        {"b","d"},
        {"f","a"},
        {"d","c"}
    };
    Graph g(projects,dependencies);
    bool temp=g.BuildOrder();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is your adjacency list data structure a vector of pairs of a set and vector? 
If it is what we normally call an adjacency list -- meaning the adjacency list representation of a graph -- it should be a vector<vector<int>> or an unordered_map<int, vector<int>> if you want your vertices to be integers as you seem to want to,

Comment: Hello, at first it was that way but I couldn't make it work. I made it this way now because the vector is for storing the vertexes that are dependent on the current vertex and adjecency list is for the vertexes the current vertex depends on. If I just had a vector<vector<int>> I would have to iterate through all the vertexes to delete the vertexes with 0 ingoing edges. or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Oh I see, you need the edges coming in to a vertex ... so this is Kahn’s algorithm as described in Wikipedia? Where is your output going? Where is the topological order you are generating?

Comment: I read the idea from cracking the coding interview book but implemented it myself. So it might be kahns algorithm as you said but I wouldnt know. Its not generating the topological ordering but its returning whether its possible to have a topological order out of this graph

Comment: I looked up Kahns algorithm and it seems like yes its the same algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont totally understand what your code is doing but I think it is implementing Kahn's algorithm. The thing with Kahn's algorithm is that it requires a graph representation in which you can get the in-neighbors and the out-neighbors of a given vertex in the digraph efficiently. To me this makes it too cumbersome to bother with given that a topological sort kind of naturally falls out of a depth-first search of out-neighbors only.

Below is an implementation of the DFS way. I do it with two visited sets like they explain in the Wikipedia article, because that way you do not even need to keep track of the source vertices of the graph, the vertices with in-degree zero, when building the graph -- although if you know the sources the DFS based algorithm is even simpler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <deque>

using Edges = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
using Vertices = std::vector<std::string>;
using Graph = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>;

Graph BuildAjacencyList(const Edges& edges)
{
    Graph graph;
    for (const auto& edge : edges)
        graph[edge.first].push_back(edge.second);
    return graph;
}

Vertices FindTopologicalOrder(const Vertices& vertices, const Edges& edges)
{
    auto graph = BuildAjacencyList(edges);

    std::unordered_set<std::string> unexplored, visited;
    std::copy(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), std::inserter(unexplored, unexplored.end()));

    std::deque<std::string> topo_order;
    std::function<bool(std::string)> visit = [&](std::string vert) {
        if (unexplored.find(vert) == unexplored.end())
            return true;
        if (visited.find(vert) != visited.end())
            return false;
        visited.insert(vert);
        for (const auto& neighbor : graph[vert])
            if (!visit(neighbor))
                return false;
        visited.erase(vert);
        unexplored.erase(vert);
        topo_order.push_front(vert);
        return true;
    };

    while (!unexplored.empty())
        if (!visit(*unexplored.begin()))
            return Vertices(); // the dependency graph has a cycle.

    return Vertices(topo_order.begin(), topo_order.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> projects{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
    Edges dependencies{
        {"a","d"},
        {"f","b"},
        {"b","d"},
        {"f","a"},
        {"d","c"},
        {"b","e"}
    };

    auto order = FindTopologicalOrder(projects, dependencies);
    if (order.empty()) {
        std::cout << "there is a cycle in these dependencies\n";
    } else {
        for (const auto& vert : order)
            std::cout << vert << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for this answer, this seems like a more understandable way to topological sort indeed. But I still am not sure if the time complexity of my algorithm is as I am hoping it is O (P+D). Do you know that?

Comment: I think yours is O(P+D), yeah.